# Can Anyone Recommend a Windows Development Laptop?

Tags: development, web-development

My position was recently eliminated at a biotech where I worked for 17 years and am in the process of looking for a Windows development laptop that I can use for some training classes that I am taking in Azure technologies such as Azure DevOps, Azure Portal, Containers (Docker and Kubernetes) to get my skill set up to speed so I can hopefully find a new job.

I have a laptop, but it's terribly underpowered and have been doing some research however thought that I would check here as well..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no budget/region limitations the Framework 12th gen DIY laptop is probably best. It's repairable, stirdy and if you tell them to include Windows they will, but if you are gonna go work in Azure, you can save €150 by going Linux. It's power is pretty ok (I use the 11th gen and it's still pretty powerful) although the battery life isn't amazing on 11th gen but I think they partially fixed it on 12th and 13th gen

Edit: Since you are gonna be working in Docker and it might be nice to be able to test locally on Linux. WSL is possible though but that doesn't work as nice

Comment: Looking at this one:
https://www.bestbuy.com/site/hp-envy-17-3-full-hd-touch-screen-laptop-intel-core-i7-16gb-memory-1tb-ssd-natural-silver/6535750.p?skuId=6535750

Comment: The tutorial I am reading on Docker is recommending running Ubuntu in Hyper-V over WSL

Comment: That might be true but the guy that is doing that tutorial only knows Windows and trust me, it's easier on normal Ubuntu because with WSL you have to run 2 OSses and set up WSL while if you run Ubuntu, everything lines up (also the paths for the volumes don't line up on WSL)

Comment: It's totally possible to do WSL though just expect it to be harder than using normal Linux

Comment: The tutorial is recommended running exercises on Linux, however he says that if you're not running a Linux machine, use Hyper-V to do the exercises if that makes sense..
Thanks again

Comment: That makes total sense but from my limited experience setting up WSL is harder than installing Linux